# Ionicons don't load on cell phone, only on desktop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile, icons, desktop, ionicons

Ionicons just working at desktop local/production, but when i test in cell phone the icons appear as squares.

Obs: 
- Icons working fine on all screens at desktop; 
- Ruby on Rails project;

Comment: How do you include / load the icons?

Comment: Following the steps of github ionicons, using bower option. github.com/ionic-team/ionicons

Comment: UPDATE:
Solved using https://github.com/umhan35/ionicons-rails

Comment: You can answer your own question! If you include all relevant details (and provide a reasonable explanation why the one way works and the other don't) it will help other readers to solve the same problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll do this as soon as have a time!
I'm beginning with programming and i use the stackoverflow many times just to take a doubts, but if i can answer some questions i'll made this.